# SharePoint up/download of word files very slow

Tags: sharepoint-server, performance

I have a problem with a SharePoint 2013 Server where it most of the times takes 40-60 seconds to open a Word file from there.

The size of the file does not matter and also not if I do it in a big library or in a small one.

When I turn on the tracing I see a lot of requests which need exactly 21 seconds. This leads me to the point that for some reasons internally the  SharePoint gets a timeout.

Here are some of the request in the traces which takes exactly 21 seconds

```
http://sharepoint/sites/CRMDocuments/_layouts/15/WopiFrame.aspx?sourcedoc=%2Fsites%2FCRMDocuments%2Fincident%2FDCP%20Customization%5F57037689EBC7E41180CB00155DC8D406%2FAR%2D07688A%20Bilbrough%20Co%20Ltd%2D2%2Edoc&action=interactivepreview&wdSmallView=1 

http://sharepoint/sites/CRMDocuments/incident/DCP%20Customization_57037689EBC7E41180CB00155DC8D406/

http://sharepoint/sites/CRMDocuments/_vti_bin/cellstorage.svc/CellStorageService
```

The same url requests are sometimes quick.

I have really no idea where I should start searching for the problem. Would be great if someone has a hint .

Answer (score 0):

If your SharePoint server does not have Internet-access, you might run into CRL-Check timeouts.

[Best Practices for CRL Checking on SharePoint Servers](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chaun/archive/2014/05/01/best-practices-for-crl-checking-on-sharepoint-servers.aspx)

Comment: The SharePoint server has internet access. Anything else I can check?

Comment: You could check your SQL-Server Logs for Errors "Using dbghelp.dll version 4.0.5". I have seen environments where this bug caused high CPU-Load on SQL-Server and make SharePoint respond slow. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chaun/archive/2013/08/01/sp2013-sql2012-database-performance-metric-provider-timer-job-using-dbghelp-dll-version-4-0-5.aspx